# Integration PowerPoint with Excel - Excel opening but blinking on the taskbar

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am a beginner in this matter, could you help me, please?
In PowerPoint, I made code linked to a CommandButton that opens a workbook, when I click on it, Excel opens, but it is flashing on the taskbar and the PowerPoint Presentation remains open. It is possible when clicking on the button Excel opens in front of the Presentation?

```vb
Private Sub cmbFAUUSP_Click()

Dim ExcApp As Excel.Application

Set ExcApp = New Excel.Application

ExcApp.Visible = True

ExcApp.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Monster PC\Desktop\tabeladedisciplinas FAUUSP.xlsx")

Set pastatrabalho = ExcApp.ActiveWorkbook

pastatrabalho.Application.ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
pastatrabalho.Application.DisplayFullScreen = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please introduce yourself ...

Answer (score 1):

If you have not, you should declare all your variables. (Use `Option Explicit` at the top of the module to help you with that, it will warn you if you forgot to declare a variable)

You don't need to set workbook for what you described so I have commented `pastatrabalho`, uncomment/remove as you need:

```
Private Sub cmbFAUUSP_Click()
    Dim ExcApp As Excel.Application
    Dim pastatrabalho As Excel.Workbook 'Uncomment / Remove as needed
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ExcApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application") 'This will retrieve the existing instance of Excel if you already have an Excel running
    On Error GoTo -1
    
    If ExcApp Is Nothing Then Set ExcApp = New Excel.Application 'Create a new instance of Excel if not
                
    ExcApp.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Monster PC\Desktop\tabeladedisciplinas FAUUSP.xlsx")
    'Replace above line with below if you need to refer to the workbook in the later part of your procedure, if any
    'Set pastatrabalho = ExcApp.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Monster PC\Desktop\tabeladedisciplinas FAUUSP.xlsx")

    With ExcApp
        'Setting Left and Top will brings Excel window to the same location as your Powerpoint (applicable if using multiple monitors)
        .Left = Application.Left
        .Top = Application.Top
        
        .Visible = True
        .WindowState = xlMaximized
        .DisplayFullScreen = True
                                                          
        .ActiveWindow.Activate
        'AppActivate ExcApp.Caption    'another way of activating, must provide the exact same title as the one shown on your Application (which can differ based on version)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I followed your instructions but Excel still keeps blinking on the taskbar

Comment: You can probably try AppActivate .ActiveWindow.Caption after .ActiveWindow.Activate line, the caption returns should match exactly how the Excel Application is labelled, (something like "Excel - Book1.xlsx")

Comment: Resulted in Run Time Error 5 - Invalid procedure call or argument on the AppActivate line

Comment: Most likely this is because AppActivate can't find the Excel Application based on .ActiveWindow.Caption. Please check that the output of .ActiveWindow.Caption is exactly the same as what's shown on your Excel Application.

Comment: Refer to this link for more info - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4213b04f-870c-4118-8472-d79992aa1993/ms-project-2013-vba-macro-appactivate-quotmicrosoft-excelquot-runtime-error-5-invalid?forum=appsforoffice

Comment: Thank you so much,i adjusted the line AppActivate .ActiveWindow.Caption to AppActivate ExcApp.Caption and it worked ! You saved me

Comment: Great! I have edited the answer to include AppActivate. Please remember to accept.